# How can I define arguments in only one variable?

Tags: java, variable-assignment

Is there a way to set one variable with several arguments?

for example:

```
String K, Q, A, J = "King", "Queen", "Ace", "Jack";
```

Which the program will understand that the **K** is set to *King* and so on

or do I have to declare each of them separately:

```
String K = "King";
```

and so far?

Comment: `String K = "King", Q = "Queen" etc`.

Comment: By simply looking at some basic java tutorial..

Comment: Without wanting to suggest that it is the be-all-and-end-all, it may be worth noting that [Google's Java style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.8.2-variable-declarations) explicitly prohibits declaring multiple variables on the same line. I think the rationale is that it's easier to read, and frankly putting the variables on the same line doesn't gain you much. I just want you to think carefully about *why* you want to do it, when some consider it worth banning.

Comment: If you're hard-coding the card values anyway (which is reasonable), an enum might be better.

Comment: "How can I define arguments in only one variable?" `String K, Q, A, J` is not one variable. It *declares* 4 separate variables. You can *assigning* values to them with `=` operator like `String K = "King", Q = "Queen", A = "Ace", J = "Jack";`

Comment: I'm starting on Java, and the assignement: "*Write a piece of code that reads a shorthand text description of a playing card and prints the longhand equivalent. The shorthand description is the card's rank (2 through 10, J, Q, K, or A) followed by its suit (C, D, H, or S). You should expand the shorthand into the form "Rank of Suit".*" ; So I was think in  set one variable to define the Letters to make it easier when I start the logic process.

Comment: @Pshemo thank you,  I didn't know the exactly terms

Comment: @Lwkyan Consider using a `Map<Character, String>`. Map the shorthand of each rank to the long form and likewise for the suits (in a second `Map` object).

Comment: @bcsb1001 I'll try this, seems more efficient

Comment: Since the suits are never going to change, consider using an enum, rather than a mutable collection type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use:

```
String K="King", Q="Queen", A="Ace", J="Jack";
```